# How do I strip the p tags with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

```
<p>
     <a href="link"><img src="image"></a>
</p>
```

Expected result: `<a href="link"><img src="image"></a>`

Answer (score 12):

You can use `replaceWith()` to replace an element with its contents:

```
$('p').replaceWith
(
    function() { return $(this).contents(); }
);
```

See [here](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/).

Answer (score 3):

You could also use [`unwrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/):

```
$("p").contents().unwrap();
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/auZXU/)

Answer (score 0):

For a particular `P` element, you can just go

```
$('p').html();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$("p").each(function(){
    var content = $(this).html();
    $(this).parent().append(content);
    $(this).remove();
});
```

searches all p-tags, gets content. Appends it to the parent element and removes the p tag. Does not work in all cases (for example if the P tags should be at the start of the parent element.)

Answer (score 0):

Give an Id to your p tag

```
<p id='id'>
     <a href="link"><img src="image"></a>
</p>
```

then use Jquery to select inner HTML

```
$('#id').html();
```

Comment: This is not what the op wants. He wants to unbox the <p>-contents, not clear them.

Answer (score 0):

give an id to it.

```
<p id="test">

<a href="link"></a>

</p>
```

then use

```
var link = $("#test")[0] ;
```

Comment: I've never seen this .[idx] before. If you mean

   $("#test")[0];

This will only select the p element.

Comment: Yeah , I meant var result = $("#test")[0]